# Why does as.POSIXlt return NA for some valid dates?

Tags: r, date, na, posixlt

I can't figure out why I'm getting TRUE from this is.na test:

```
is.na(as.POSIXlt(x = "03/09/2014 2:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
```

When this one gives me FALSE:

```
is.na(as.POSIXlt(x = "03/09/2013 2:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
```

What is it about March 9th, 2014 that R hates so bad?

Comment: I get `FALSE` for both, and both are valid dates when `tz="GMT"`

Comment: Note that in 2014 3/9 was day light savings change.  It was 3/10 in 2013.

Comment: @BrodieG: that depends on which timezone you're referring to. I'm closing this as a duplicate. I'll vote to re-open if the OP can demonstrate that it's not a timezone issue.

Comment: It's not hatred of that date, it's hatred of that hour _in_ _your_ _particular_ _locale_. R is smarter than you. In this case a reproducible example will require information from `Sys.getlocale()`

Comment: Yup, it's a duplicate. Thanks for the help everyone.